# How to operate multiple doms at the same time with angular directive？

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, angularjs-directive

I solved this problem, just < p [appHighlight]="markArray" #mark>111< /p >, and set '@Input('appHighlight') mark: Array' in highlight.directive.ts.

refer to: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ewavt

Thanks for all answer, and welcome other solutions.

---

Question Desc:

This is HTML:

```
<p appHighlight>111</p>
<p appHighlight>222</p>
<p appHighlight>333</p>
```

This is directive.ts:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }

  @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
    console.log(this.el);   
    // only output current mouse-hover DOM ElementRef
    // but I want to get all DOM's ElementRef whose bound appHighlight
    // in highlight.directive.ts, NOT xxx.component.ts
    // in pursuit of better decouple and reuse.
  }
}
```

I want :

When the mouse is hover one of the DOM elements, all DOMs bound with the appHighlight instruction are triggered.

The question is how to get the DOM ElementRef of all bound elements in **directive.ts**, NOT xxx.component.ts ? (because in pursuit of better decouple and reuse.)

Thanks.

Comment: the [ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) decorator gives you exactly that

Comment: You wont get all the DOM ElementRef who is bound to appHighlight directive inside that directive. You can get that in the component where you are using it(parent).

Comment: but I want to implement control in directive.ts, not in component.ts. how to pass ViewChildren into directive.ts? you know, data is rendered after DOM attributes sets, so I can't pass ViewChildren by '<p [highlight]="#...(ViewChildren)...">'.Thanks

Comment: @leo We're missing the context. what is the reason for which you wish to keep logic in the directive (don't...) and not in the component ?

Comment: I want to get DOM-List in highlight.directive.ts, not xxx.component.ts，because in pursuit of better decouple and reuse.

Answer (score 0):

the [ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) decorator gives you exactly that:

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChildren(HighlightDirective, {read: ElementRef) children: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  // ...

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.children.forEach(child => console.log(child.nativeElement));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thks, but I want to get DOM-List in highlight.directive.ts, not xxx.component.ts，because in pursuit of better decouple and reuse.

Comment: I solved this problem, just <p [appHighlight]="mark" #mark>111</p>, and set '@Input('appHighlight') mark: Array<any>' in highlight.directive.ts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for all the elements inside the directive then it is not the right place to look into. If you need all the elements which are bound to `appHighlight` directive then you should look that in the parent component.

```
export class AppComponent  {
    @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
     this.highlights.forEach(highlight => console.log(highlight));
  }
  @ViewChildren(HighlightDirective, { read: ElementRef }) highlights: QueryList<ElementRef>

  name = 'Angular';
}
```

Here we are now listening to `mouseenter` in `AppComponent` rather than inside 
`HighlightDirective` .

Working [Stackblitz](https://angular-1ykp45.stackblitz.io)

Comment: Thks, but I want to get DOM-List in highlight.directive.ts, not xxx.component.ts，because in pursuit of better decouple and reuse.

Comment: I solved this problem, just <p [appHighlight]="mark" #mark>111</p>, and set '@Input('appHighlight') mark: Array<any>' in highlight.directive.ts. Thanks.

Comment: Can you fork the stackblitz and post your answer?